# Apache Spark - Performance with and without using Case Classes

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, case-class

I have 2 datasets, customers and orders

I want to join both on customer key.

I tried two approaches, one using case classes and one without.

**Using Case classes:** -> Just takes forever to complete - almost 11 minutes

```
case class Customer(custKey: Int, name: String, address: String, phone: String, acctBal: String, mktSegment: String, comment: String) extends Serializable

case class Order(orderKey: Int, custKey: Int, orderStatus: String, totalPrice: Double, orderDate: String, orderQty: String, clerk: String, shipPriority: String, comment: String) extends Serializable

val customers = sc.textFile("customersFile").map(row => row.split('|')).map(cust => (cust(0).toInt, Customer(cust(0).toInt, cust(1), cust(2), cust(3), cust(4), cust(5), cust(6))))
val orders = sc.textFile("ordersFile").map(row => row.split('|')).map(order => (order(1).toInt, Order(order(0).toInt, order(1).toInt, order(2), order(3).toDouble, order(4), order(5), order(6), order(7), order(8))))

orders.join(customers).take(1)
```

**Without Case classes** -- completes in few seconds

```
val customers = sc.textFile("customersFile").map(row => row.split('|'))
val orders = sc.textFile("ordersFile").map(row => row.split('|'))
val customersByCustKey = customers.map(row => (row(0), row)) // customer key is the first column in customers rdd, hence row(0) 
val ordersByCustKey = orders.map(row => (row(1), row)) //  customer key is the second column in orders rdd, hence row(1) 

ordersByCustKey.join(customersByCustKey).take(1)
```

Want to know if this due to the time taken for serialization/deserialization while using case classes?

if yes, in which cases is it recommended to use case classes?

Job details using case classes:
[image: Job Details - Case Classes]

Job details without case classes:
[image: Job details without case classes]

Comment: It has to be with that, in memory serialization and take a look to the amount of shuffle. Have you tested with Kryo?

Comment: Maybe it's the number of fields to serialize and deserialize. In the second one, there are only two fields to serialize and the first one, there are many.